# Draw curve container like image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[Container ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JtGL.png)

This is my ui and now i want to drow curve inside container like give my images.and also want gradient color to my code.

Ui like same to same given images.

Please give me proper solution and code of this my images..

Thanks...

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve? The image you attached is just a design, or is it something that you have already developed?

Comment: You need to use CustomPainter class to achieve this. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html
Refer through this documentation to create the specific design.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this sites to draw every you wants

[fluttershapemaker.com](https://fluttershapemaker.com/)

[svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)